# Updating record in model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 app I'm currently moving my logic into my models.

One method in my model changes the status of a booking:

```
def withdraw
  if self.status == 1 #only allow bookings with status 1 to be updated
    self.status = 2
    GuestMailer.booking_withdrawn(self).deliver
    save!
  end
end
```

I call the method from my **BookingsController** like so:

```
if @booking.withdraw
  flash[:success] = 'The booking has been withdrawn'
end
```

My question is should I be using `save!` in the model as I'm only updating?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `save!` in this method. However, the method can be renamed to `withdraw!` to show that this method changes the state of the object and throws an exception if the model cannot be saved.